# Alert for apple push notification certificate expiration

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I had created an App Id and enabled Push notification service in clients's apple developer account. This certificate had expired in november 2011.

Do apple send any email if push notification certificate (Production Push SSL Certificate) is going to expired or has expired?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no - i'm afraid there is no such warning mail from apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Apple does not send a warning email if your push notification certificate is about to expire.  I also learned this through experience :)

Comment: Yes. Thank you :) 
And even if it is expired they show status as enabled with green round mark. It should at least show that it is expired or red mark.

Answer (score 2):

I think they started to do that for the agent account.
they send an email 30 days before the push certificate expires.

Comment: Yes, now the email is sent to the Agent 30 days before. Should be nice to configure to which member send the email to... but cannot find any kind of such configuration...

Comment: Who is agent? I don't see it in user types